# in linear programming how to relate an integer variable with a binary one

Tags: mixed-integer-programming

mixed integer linear programming
problem of assigning operations to machines and each operation require number of operators. there is a limited number of available resource (operators).
during the solution $S_i$ is determined.
my question is:
I don't know how to connect constraint 1 with 2
how to say when $S_i$ starting time of operation i starts at time t  then $X_{ijt} = 1 ? $         for example, if $S_1 = 5 $ and assigned to machine 2 then $X_{125}=1$
Indices
t time index 1...T
j machine index 1...M
parameters
$res_i $ is resource requirement of job i
$p_ij$ is processing time of operation i on machine j
b is available resource
$A_j$ ready time of machine j

variables
$ S_i$ is an operation start time
decision variables
$ X_{ijt} = 1$ if operation i on machine j starts at time t and 0 otherwise
$ Z_{ij} = 1 $ if operation i is assigned to machine j, and 0 otherwise

$Si \geq 0 $ and integer i=1...N
$X_{ijt} ∈ {0, 1}, ∀i ∈ N, ∀ j ∈ M, t ∈ T$

$Si \le \sum_{j \in M}  A_j Z_{ij} ...(1) $  determine starting time for each operation
$\sum_{i\in N}\sum_{j \in M}\sum_{s=max{0,t-p_{ij}}}^{t-1} res_i \times  X_{ijs} \le b$   t =1...T    (2) ensure that the total number of operators assigned to operations doesn't exceed the available operators at any time period.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you please [edit] your post and improve it's formattin? See some tips on [ask], on [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and on writing down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already.

Comment: What are $A_k$, $Z_i$, $\text{res}_i$, and $b$? Also, constraint (2) is indexed over $t$ but also contains a sum over $t$.

Comment: @RobPratt I have edited my question again with more clarification. there are more constraints in this problem but I only mentioned the two that I want to relate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don’t quite follow, but maybe you want this:
$$S_i = \sum_{j,t} t\ X_{i,j,t}$$

Comment: thanks, yes I think so. do you think I need to add this: $\sum_{j,t} X_{ijt} = 1 $ i = 1...N

Comment: Yes, I thought that was probably one of the constraints you just didn't show.